# JavaScript - Date function throwing "is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, date

I am very new to JavaScript and it took me some time to come up with the following function in order to get current date and subtract a year from it:

```
function getDate() {
    var now = new Date();
    // get current timezone specific date/time
    // timezoneoffset value converts returned offset value to milliseconds
    // get current date value - 1 year
    var dateMinusOneYear = new Date(now.getTime() - 31556952000) + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    var dateStr =
        ("0000" + (dateMinusOneYear.getFullYear())).slice(-4) + "-" +
        ("00" + (dateMinusOneYear.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
        ("00" + dateMinusOneYear.getDate()).slice(-2);
    return (dateStr);
}
```

When I invoke the function, I get the following error:
TypeError: dateMinusOneYear.getFullYear is not a function

Can anyone please advise? Some might advise to not use the new Date method at all due to problematic reasons, but I have to use it specifically for some unrelated reasons.

Comment: You don’t have a Date object anymore after doing a `+` operation; you have a number. You need to wrap the sum in another `new Date` constructor.

Comment: There is a typo,`)` must be at the end of `60000`.

Comment: ECMAScript offsets have the opposite sense to common offsets, i.e. west is +ve and east is -ve, so likely you want to subtract the offset, not add it. Subtracting a year via milliseconds isn't a good idea, much better to just decrement the year and handle leap years (should 29 Feb - 1 year be 28 Feb or 1 Mar?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense at all

```
 new Date(now.getTime() - 31556952000) + (now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

Maybe you were trying to accomplish this?

```
   new Date(now.getTime() - 31556952000 + now.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

Comment: And `getTime()` is redundant. :-)